# Using different indentation for Jade

Tags: pug

From [this tutorial](http://www.franz-enzenhofer.com/jade) it seems that Jade requires 2-spaces tabs. Can I use another tabbing syntax with Jade?

Comment: This tutorial is more recent: http://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not necessary to use only two spaces for tabbing.

You can use any number of spaces (consistently) or a tab character to indent. The only quirk is you can't use both spaces and tabs at the same time, or it will give an error while compiling.

See this link [Jade](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade).

Comment: Any idea why this is (inability to mix tabs and spaces)? I constantly get errors when I'm splicing different developers templates together, and it doesn't seem to make any sense to me why this is the case.

Comment: @Laser check https://github.com/jadejs/jade/issues/280 - I think it should be reopened!

Answer (score 0):

The tab size must be 4, when I use gulp-template.